# looking for a way to remove security token from URL

Tags: java, jsp, security, post, get

my web application has multiple jsp tags where the GET method is being called and security token is part of the URL.Now after the last security review we have been asked to remove security token from the URL. What are the options I have here ?What is the best approach ? Thank you in advance for any input!

jsp

```
<a href="<c:url value="sortCompany.do?sortFieldName=CHECK_SERIAL_NUMBER&amp;${csrf:token(pageContext)}"/>"><fmt:message key="label.chkNbr" /></a>
```

java method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = SORT_URL_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String sortCompany(
                @PathVariable("userType") String userType,
                WebRequest webRequest,
                @RequestParam(required = true, value = "sortFieldName") String sortFieldName,
                ModelMap modelView) {

            DataTableViewer<Company
> dataTableViewer = getDataTableViewer(webRequest);
            dataTableViewer.toggleColumnSortOrder(sortFieldName);

            initializeModelView(modelView, webRequest);

            return SUCCESS_VIEW;
        }
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Disclosure_of_Token_in_URL *"The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only respond to POST requests. This is in fact what the RFC 2616 requires for GET requests. If sensitive server-side actions are guaranteed to only ever respond to POST requests, then there is no need to include the token in GET requests."*

Comment: Thanks for the response.But how to achieve this from the technical standpoint.Does it mean I need to user a form ?Can it be done without a form ?What code in jsp would I need instead of my current <a href ?

Comment: Forms are one way. Or you use AJAX with POSTs to update the site. Or you simply don't put a CSRF token in the href. But only when the GET request is actually a request that does not change state. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: all GET requests in the application do not change state. Does it mean that I can remove CSRF token from all GET requests and on server validate security token only on my POST requests ?

Comment: I guess so. Requests that can't do harm don't need to be protected from being forged by 3rd parties. The point of CSRF is that, when you're browing on a malicous website, it can make you send requests to another site that you're still authenticated with. And because it's a site you're authenticated with your browser sends all the right cookies, but the request can be made up by evil people. The site can still make you do a GET request for a sorted list of companies or whatever it is that  you have, but it's not going to change anything for the user